# Mac getting stuck during update

Tags: macos, startup

So I'm updating the new macOS Monterey, but what's happening is the bar is freezing at the end of the update. I have waited multiple hours and left it overnight, but in the end, the bar is just frozen; it isn't moving an inch. So what I did is, I went to recovery mode, and went to macOS utilities, and reinstalled macOS Monterey, and selected that it should install on my Macintosh HD disk (where all my data is on), but however, even after this, it is still just freezing at the end of the bar, at around 95%. I reset the NVRAM and the SMC as well, but nothing is working. Previously, I booted it up on safe mode by holding shift, and it worked, but those were for shut downs. This is a reinstallation and I tried booting it up on safe mode, but it isn't working, it's still just freezing at the end of the update. **And also, if I reinstall  macOS Monterey, will all of my data and files and applications still be there? Because that Macintosh HD startup disk does contain all my data.** Anyways, any clue on what's going on? Thanks for the help!

Edit : Results of `diskutil list internal` command from recovery mode :

```
xxxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyy-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list internal
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨My Data⁩                 108.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 508.6 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                2.2 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      20.5 KB    disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.7 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨Aarush Data⁩             847.9 KB   disk1s7
   7:                APFS Volume ⁨The correct disk⁩        737.3 KB   disk1s8
   8:                APFS Volume ⁨Untitled - Data⁩         38.1 GB    disk1s9
   9:                APFS Volume ⁨Untitled⁩                15.7 GB    disk1s10
  10:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.7 GB    disk1s10s1
  11:                APFS Volume ⁨Untitled 2⁩              720.9 KB   disk1s11
```

Comment: Have you a save Time Machine or other of your datas?   Else in Recovery Mode/Restaure Time Machine, you should have the choice of restoring your system before the update with the snapshots created automatically before a system update.

Comment: Yes I have that, the only problem is when restarting, the bar freezes at the end.

Comment: When you restore from Time Machine? If you boot in Verbose Mode (cmd+v at boot) have you some informations?

Comment: It just shows a bunch of code or something. Like some white lines of text which just keep on going down. Right now, the only issue is the bar is freezing at the end of the update. That's it.

Comment: Can you see repetitive messages as "too many corpses.."

Comment: @Jean_JD Yes, I can.

Comment: Can you boot in Recovery Mode, then open terminal from top menu/utilities. Here you open a second terminal (cmd+n) and you execute the following command :`/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari `  this will open a Safari windows and you can connect to the forum. In the initial terminal you execute the command : `diskutil list internal ` and you add the results (in text mode) at your initial question.

Comment: If possible could you please give it to me step-wise. Like:

Step 1: ...
Step 2: ...
Step 3: ...
etc.

Just for easier understandability. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've do that : https://pastebin.com/EcFSPFLw

Comment: Ok, and so what does this do?

Comment: And what are the results, necessary for the rest of the commands.

Comment: I did it. It opened the safari window and showed some stuff on the terminal. Then I typed diskutil list internal and clicked enter in the terminal. But It did nothing.

Comment: Never mind. This is what it says after typing "diskutil list internal": https://pastebin.com/wApk8UnW

Comment: Are you sure to be in Recovery Mode when you give the `diskutil list internal` results?

Comment: Yes I am in recovery mode when I give the diskutil list internal results.

Comment: Ok. So in Recovery mode, can you execute the command : `diskutil ap listgroups disk1` and give the results in a pastebin link?

Comment: It says "disk 1 is not an APFS container."

Comment: Ok, so replace disk1 with the good container disk ID(`diskutil list` can help you).

Comment: Sorry never mind it says this: https://pastebin.com/3Ycyb7ik

Comment: Ok. Now you can try : `diskutil mount disk1s1` If ok you can give the results of `ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/Caches/opendirectory`

Comment: Ok, see what I did now is, right now I am on safe boot on my Macintosh HD startup disk. I want to switch to normal mode. So for that, I restarted and shut down my computer. Then, as usual, the Apple Logo and the Progress Bar appears. However, the Progress Bar keeps on freezing at around 30% in the update. To be specific, the Progress Bar loads up till 25%, jumps to 90% and then immediately jumps back to 30% and just freezes.

Comment: Also, when I try: diskutil mount disk1s1, it says this: Volume My Data on disk1s1 mounted

When I try: ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/Caches/opendirectory, it says this:
(base) aayuvreddy@Aayuvs-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\HD/var/db/Caches/opendirectory 
ls: /Volumes/MacintoshHD/var/db/Caches/opendirectory: No such file or directory

Comment: If you are in safe mode, this is not correct. For recovery mode, you need to start by pressing the cmd and r keys at the same time.